# Import qgis.core and tkinter in one application

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, tkinter

I try to import `modules:qgis.core` and `tkinter` in one application, but I have a problem `:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'.`

I add to Path: `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.1\apps\Python39` and I set `PYTHONPATH` `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.1\apps\qgis\python`

Normally without QGIS installed (when the QGIS PATH in Inv Var is not added) tkinter works fine.

Here is the script:

```
import os, sys, glob
from qgis.core import *
import tkinter
```

But I am getting error:

```
 import tkinter 
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.1\apps\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I have the same issue on QGIS 3.16 Python 3.7

Answer (score 2):

On *Windows* (but not on *Linux* or *MacOS*), *QGis* is installed with is own *python* version. But this version does not include the `tkinter` library (probably to lighten the installation).

You can probably install the `tkinter` library with `pip install` but I don't advise it, it could break the *Qgis* installation.

I advise you to install **miniconda**, which will allow you to create a virtual environment in which you will install an independent *Qgis.* To do this, fellow this steps :

1. Install [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)
2. Launch the miniconda shell
3. Create a new virtual environement : `conda create --name test_qgis`
4. Activate the virtual env : `conda activate test_qgis`
5. Install qgis : `conda install -c conda-forge qgis`

If everything worked well, when you run python (*in the virtual env*) you will have access to *qgis* and *tkiner*

```
(test_qgis) C:\Users\ATM>python
Python 3.9.7 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Sep 29 2021, 19:15:42) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import qgis.core
>>> import tkinter
>>>
```